# My mysql queried returned with wrong data

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT * FROM gbtss.weighing where indate between '04/02/2019' and '04/08/2019';
```

I want to retrieve data data between these two dates, but the above command doesn't work in mysql workbench.

Comment: Please share the error that is being displayed.

Comment: Can you share the output of "SHOW CREATE TABLE gbtss.weighing"

Answer (score 4):

Use valid MySQL date literals:

```
SELECT *
FROM gbtss.weighing
WHERE indate BETWEEN '2019-02-04' AND '2019-08-04';
```

I assume here that `04/08/2018` means the fourth of August, 2018.  If it means the either of April, 2018, then use `'2019-04-08'` instead.

See the MySQL [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html) for valid date literal formats.

If you are actually storing plain text into `indate`, then you would also have to do an additional step of calling `STR_TO_DATE` on that column:

```
SELECT *
FROM gbtss.weighing
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(indate, '%d/%M/%Y') BETWEEN '2019-02-04' AND '2019-08-04';
```

Comment: No, still returned nothing.

Comment: Is `indate` a date column, or is it actually literal `text`?

Comment: it's a date column but the format is dd/mm/yyyy. i tried this dd-mm-yyyy as u said but cannot

Comment: Your comment makes no sense, and date columns have no "format."  I think you are storing text into `indate`, and you should try using `STR_TO_DATE`.